# OnCheckedChangeListener don't work with a Switch in the Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I tried to add an "OnCheckedChangeListener" to a Switch in the Toolbar of my Android App. But if I click at the Switch don`t get the Log output in the Android Monitor (logcat). There are also no Exceptions in the log.
**The MainActivity:**

```
LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_switch, null);

toolbarSwitch = (Switch) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.switch_toolbar);
toolbarSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        Log.d("SMSAT", "Test");
    }
});
```

**This is the Layout of the Switch:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/switch_toolbar"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:checked="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**The Menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_switch_toolbar"
    android:title="@string/menu_switch"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_switch"></item>

</menu>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where do you initialize the toolbar?

Comment: Do you mean this? `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }`

Comment: No the part where you `toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` and `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: Ok this is in the onCreate method in the MainActivity

Comment: where is it in relation to setting the switch listener? Show the code please

Comment: I edidet my Question an added the Code :)

Comment: Try setting up the switch listener before calling `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: Thank you for your help but an User answered my Question and this worked but i think he deleted his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move my Code in the onCreateOptionsMenu Method.

Here is the Code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    View textEntryView = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_switch_toolbar).getActionView();

    toolbarSwitch = (Switch) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.switch_toolbar);
    toolbarSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            Log.d("SMSAT", "Test");
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```